# My listitem is not getting clicked

Tags: android

I have declared my setonitemclick listener in my show category dataloaded method. There is a toast which is not getting fired if an item is clicked in the list.This dataloaded method is called in my receivertask class where the list is populated by the server data

```
        #Activity class#

        private ArrayList <CategoryModel>categoryList;  

            //private static final String[]paths = {"All", "Favourites"};



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(com.bioscope.R.layout.categorylist);
                save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);


                RecieveCategoriesTask task = new RecieveCategoriesTask(this,"all");
                task.execute();


                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            public void showcateogryDataLoaded(ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList) {

                    this.categoryList = categoryList;



                    for(CategoryModel c:categoryList)
                    {
                        Log.v("title", c.getTitle());   
                    }

                    CategorysListAdapter adapter=new CategorysListAdapter(this, categoryList);

                    list=(ListView) findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.listView1);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    >>list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(CategorySelectonActivity.this, "You Clicked an item ",                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.print("done");
                              //showEventInformaion(position);  



                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
                                    if(cb.isChecked())
                                     cb.setChecked(false);
                                    else 
                                     cb.setChecked(true);
                        }
                    });


            }
```

In listview i have set clickable true

```
#categorylist xml#

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp" >
        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">    



          </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>  

        <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true" >
        </ListView>




    </LinearLayout>


     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="bottom"
        >

        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="SAVE" 
            android:background="#0099cc"
            />

    </RelativeLayout> 



</RelativeLayout>
```

## categoryListItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_icon"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
        android:text="Category Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category_title"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#ffcccccc"
        android:text="Cateogry Description" />



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/select_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/category_title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/category_title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffcccccc"
        android:text=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Receivertask

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
String responseString;

CategorySelectonActivity appContext;
CreateEventActivity createeventActivity_appContext;

String url;
String pageUrl = "get-event-category";
private  String userIdParameter="user_id=";

// String name,email,pass,phone;

public RecieveCategoriesTask(CategorySelectonActivity c, String critiria) {
    appContext = c;
    // url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl + critiria;
    // url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl;
    url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/getusercategory?"+userIdParameter+"259214143443955553";
    Log.i("url", url);
}

public RecieveCategoriesTask(CreateEventActivity createEventActivity,
        String critiria) {
    createeventActivity_appContext = createEventActivity;
    // url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl + critiria;
    // url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl;
    url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/getusercategory?"+userIdParameter+"259214143443955553";
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(appContext==null?createeventActivity_appContext:appContext);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading Categories...");
    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();

}

String filterResponseString(String r) {
    return r.replace("\r\n", "");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;

    try {

        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
            responseString = filterResponseString(responseString);

        } else {
            // Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();

            Utility.showMessage(appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    dialog.dismiss();

    if (responseString != null) {
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
        ;
        JSONArray jsonArr;

        try {

            Log.v("json", responseString);

            jsonArr = new JSONArray(responseString);
            // jsonArr = events.getJSONArray("events");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                CategoryModel category = new CategoryModel();

                category.setId(jsonObj.getString("event_cat_id"));
                category.setTitle(jsonObj.getString("event_cat_title"));
                category.setDescription(jsonObj.getString("event_cat_desc"));
                category.setStatus(jsonObj.getBoolean("status"));

                // event.setLogo(jsonObj.getString("logo").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

                /*
                 * event.setStartDate(jsonObj.getString("startDate"));
                 * event.setEndDate(jsonObj.getString("endDate"));
                 * 
                 * event.setStartTime(jsonObj.getString("startTime"));
                 * event.setEndTime(jsonObj.getString("endTime"));
                 * event.setCountry(jsonObj.getString("country"));
                 * event.setCity(jsonObj.getString("city"));
                 * event.setAddress(jsonObj.getString("address"));
                 * event.setLogo(jsonObj.getString("logo"));
                 * event.setBanner(jsonObj.getString("banner"));
                 * event.setPhone(jsonObj.getString("phone"));
                 * event.setEmail(jsonObj.getString("email"));
                 * 
                 * event.setWeblink(jsonObj.getString("weblink"));
                 * event.setPublishDate(jsonObj.getString("publishDate"));
                 * event.setCategoryId(jsonObj.getString("categoryId"));
                 */
                categoryList.add(category);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (appContext != null)
        {
            appContext.showcateogryDataLoaded(categoryList);
```

//              CategorySelectonActivity c=new CategorySelectonActivity();
//              c.visibleSaveButton();

```
        }
        // appContext.showCategoryListDataLoaded(responseString);
        if(createeventActivity_appContext!=null){

            createeventActivity_appContext.showcateogryDataLoaded(categoryList);
        }

    }

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Do anything with response..
}
```

what am i missing??

Comment: Show `Receivertask` class.

Comment: can you put your listitem xml?

Comment: done check.@Moradiya Akash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting any error (force close)?

See this code :

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
```

Change it to :

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
```

Because i **dont** see you have any `CheckBox` in your `Activitiy's` layout, so the `CheckBox` should be in your list item. Hence, you should use `view` from `onItemClick`'s param when using `findViewById`

**UPDATE**

Try to add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your `CheckBox` item.

Comment: yes the checkbox is in a listitem and their is no force close.The problem is item is not getting clicked but checkboxes are clickable i just want to click the row.

Comment: @FaymeShahriar Ok, so its true the problem is your `onListItem` is not fired at all. BTW, you still need to implement my answer, it will give another error if you dont fix it :)

Comment: done and has updated my question were i have added the list item.But why the item is not getting clicked!!

Comment: tnx.By fixing it list item is now getting clicked @Blaze